Image-mode change svg background
When I open a svg generated with mermaid in a buffer the diagram has no background and is unreadable on my dark theme.
How do I tell emacs to force a background color for svg files?
I read How do I force SVG figures to appear inline on a white background? but i do not want to use org mode as my goal is to use mermaid-mode 's mermaid-compile keybinding.
The svg I use seems fine :
1 <svg [..]  style="max-width: 1689.5px; background-color: rgb(245, 66, 108);" [...]

I also tried forcing the svg to have a background color with mmdc -i mydiagram.mermaid -o output.svg -b '#F5426C' and the svg displays fine in firefox but not in emacs.
Thanks

The linked answer does not use Org mode at all: it just advises create-image. It uses a poorly named variable (org-inline-image-background) in the code to be included in your init file, but you can just rename the variable.

I renamed the variable in the linked answers to image-background-override-color to make it clear that they don't have anything to do with Org mode.

Thank you, I did not read your answer straight when I posted.
